# Error in Selenium Webdriver finding element in DOM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i am trying to run tests on Selenium webdriver.

sometimes i get an error saying that the element is stale and cannot be located and this happens when i am clicking on a button on the second page of my website at:

```
 bookNowButton.click();
```

it is intermittent and doesnt happen on every test run

i introduced a "wait" but it doesn't seem to make a difference

has anyone ever had this happen before and how did you solve it?

error message:

```
test.java > Test - Chrome > com.bookinggo.ticketed.uiendtoend.TicketedReturnJourneyTest > return_tc03 FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.25)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.25 (a0c95f440512e06df1c9c206f2d79cc20be18bb1-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#271}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

full code:

```
public boolean waitForPageCheckOutPageToLoad() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait waitPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        waitPage.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='bui-button__text']")));
        return TRUE;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public void clickBookNowButton()
{
    waitForPageCheckOutPageToLoad();
    WebElement bookNowButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='bui-button__text']"));
    bookNowButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

- The element has been deleted entirely.
- The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

  [**Refrence**](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

Try this code wait for the element until it is accessible.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(@Nullable WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("checkoutLink")).click();
        return true;
    }
});
```